# Custom sort Map Java

Tags: java, android, sorting, hashmap

i have some troubles when i want to sort a map, when i create a map passing a string, it comes organized like

```
nombre=EDIFICADORA JUANA, descripcion=  LOS frst com MEJORES Estamso para servir LOS, correo1=rst008@guan.com, correo2=oipoa@gmaio.com, numero1=24602254, numero2=55655545
```

When i create a map using this data it comes disordered, this is the method that creates the map:

```
   private HashMap<String, String> getMap(String rawData) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String[] pairs = rawData.split(","); // split into key-value pairs
    for(String pair: pairs) {
        pair = pair.trim(); // get rid of extraneous white-space
        String[] components = pair.split("=");
        String key = components[0].trim();
        String value = components[1].trim();
        map.put(key, value); // put the pair into the map
    }
    return map;
}
```

This function returns something like:

0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5854} "correo2" -> "oipoa@gmaio.com"

1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5855} "correo1" -> "rst008@guan.com"`

2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5856} "numero2" -> "55655545"

3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5857} "nombre" -> "EDIFICADORA JUANA"

4 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5858} "descripcion" -> "LOS frst com MEJORES Estamso 
par"

5 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5859} "numero1" -> "24602254"

**How can i sort this Map like the string value comes?**

I expect:

0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5857} "nombre" -> "EDIFICADORA JUANA"

1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5858} "descripcion" -> "LOS frst com MEJORES Estamso par"

2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5855} "correo1" -> "rst008@guan.com"`

3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5854} "correo2" -> "oipoa@gmaio.com"

4 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5859} "numero1" -> "24602254"

5 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5856} "numero2" -> "55655545"

Comment: "How can i sort this Map like the string value comes?" I am not sure to get you. Can you give a sample of the expected output ?

Comment: Ok!, sorry @davidxxx

Comment: The different order of `numero` (last in your string) and `correo` (last in your map) is on purpose? Because that's not "like the string value comes" in my book.

Comment: Sorry again, i edited @davidxxx, can i use LinkedHashMap for this question?

Comment: @Johan Sánchez Ok I get you. You want to keep the order in the passed `String` : `"nombre=EDIFICADORA JUANA, descripcion=  LOS frst com MEJORES Estamso para servir LOS, correo1=rst008@guan.com, correo2=oipoa@gmaio.com, numero1=24602254, numero2=55655545`"

Comment: Don't be sorry :) Yes you can and even you have to. I did you an answer.

Comment: Yes! I debugged and i replace the HashMap method to LinkedHashMap and the map is like the string comes @davidxxx

Comment: You should not be using a map here at all--you should be using a custom class.

Comment: I know i can implements Parcelable or Serializable in the custom class but the problem is that i dont know how many numbers or emails comes in the string value. @chrylis

Comment: So use lists for those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `HashMap`, use the [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) implementation of `Map`.
It keeps the insertion order in your map when you iterate on :

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with
>   predictable iteration order.

So do this change :

```
   private LinkedHashMap<String, String> getMap(String rawData) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // change
    String[] pairs = rawData.split(","); // split into key-value pairs
    for(String pair: pairs) {
        pair = pair.trim(); // get rid of extraneous white-space
        String[] components = pair.split("=");
        String key = components[0].trim();
        String value = components[1].trim();
        map.put(key, value); // put the pair into the map
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), this will keep the insertion order.

Simply replace

```
new HashMap<>();
```

with

```
new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're using a HashMap. From their docs:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time

You're looking for something that maintains the order you are putting things into the map, so a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) could help. If that isn't enough for you, you could write your own Map implementation that implements [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! @SaxyPandaBear , appreciate it!